# How do you feel ? and How are you feeling?

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage, verbs, stative-verbs

Why a state verb FEEL is used in How are you feeling? question? I know it has also a dynamic meaning - touch or exemine -but in this question the meaning is different, in`t it

Comment: "How do you feel about... [something]?" - What is your general attitude towards it?  "How are you feeling?" - What is your physical or emotional state at the moment?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the verb "feel" can indeed be used both as a stative verb and a dynamic verb. In the question "How are you feeling?" it is used as a stative verb, which refers to a temporary state or condition, often related to emotions or physical sensations. This usage is common in English to inquire about someone's current emotional or physical state.

In contrast, when "feel" is used as a dynamic verb, it refers to the action of touching or examining something by touch. For example, "I feel the fabric to check its texture."

So, while "feel" can have different meanings based on context, in the question "How are you feeling?" it specifically asks about someone's present emotional or physical state. The use of the continuous tense "are feeling" emphasizes the temporary nature of this state.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. In this regard Have the rule of not using stative verbs in continuous form any meaning ?

Comment: @TatianaKirova You're welcome! The rule about not using stative verbs in continuous form is flexible. In informal English, stative verbs can be used in continuous form to express temporary or changing states. For example, "I'm feeling tired" emphasizes that the tiredness is temporary. Language evolves, and such usage can add expressiveness to speech.